# Is $SU(n)$ a CW group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups, cw-complexes, grassmannian

A CW-group $G$ is a topological group with a CW structure such that both the multiplication and the inversion are cellular. It is known that $O(n)$, $U(n)$, and $Sp(n)$ can be given CW-group structures: for the CW structures given in Steenrod and Epstein, *[Cohomology Operations](https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/steenrod-epstein.pdf)*, Chap. IV, it is not hard to check that the relevant maps are cellular.

$SU(n)$ can be given a CW structure, via the homeomorphism $SU(n) \approx G_{\mathbb C}(n,1) := U(n)/U(1)$. This is what was done in *[Cohomology Operations](https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/steenrod-epstein.pdf)*, as well as "[On the cell structures of $SU(n)$ and $Sp(n)$](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1195525543)," but my understanding is that this does not make $SU(n)$ a CW-group.

Can $SU(n)$ be given a CW-group structure? Is there any theorem addressing the question as to when a topological group can be given a CW-group structure?